# Is there a plugin that limit the number of Jenkins builds within a certain amount of time?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I do not want my team to be able to click on build link and run build job too often. I want them to be able to click after say an hour passed after the most recent build.

Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you trigger your jobs through source code changes? That's the whole point of automating the process.

Answer (score 0):

You can setup automatic schedule to build every 1 hour only.
You can setup SCM polling to poll SCM everyone 1 hour only.

Answer (score 0):

Branch API plugin allows to limit builds for a branch to a certain rate: 
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Branch+API+Plugin

[image: Example]